# Gradle build error when importing project of android studio from github

Tags: android

Hi dear I import a project from github but when gradle is build this error I am facing please help me for that

```
Error:Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3.+.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
Required by:
    androidstudio-accelerometer-gps-master:WhenMoving:unspecified
```

This is the link of github project :
[enter link description here](https://github.com/alanszlosek/androidstudio-accelerometer-gps)

Answer (score 0):

Might not help too much, but what did work for me is that I had to go to Gradle website and download the newest Gradle and install it. Although I am running a mac and a lot of work is needed to properly prepare the environment variables for mac, but in the sense that you could possibly have the same issue I would suggest that.

Go to Gradle website, by Googling it and download the latest Gradle files.